# Is there any way to get a refund for a game bought from Steam?

Tags: steam

Is it possible?

If it is, do I have to have had some sort of technical problem or can I get a refund just because I didn't like it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This policy has **just** changed.

Now it's possible to ask for a refund within 14 days of purchase, provided you have played it for less than two hours.

> You can request a refund for nearly any purchase on Steam—for any
>   reason. Maybe your PC doesn't meet the hardware requirements; maybe
>   you bought a game by mistake; maybe you played the title for an hour
>   and just didn't like it.
>
> It doesn't matter. Valve will, upon request via help.steampowered.com,
>   issue a refund for any reason, if the request is made within fourteen
>   days of purchase, and the title has been played for less than two
>   hours. There are more details below, but even if you fall outside of
>   the refund rules we’ve described, you can ask for a refund anyway and
>   we’ll take a look.
>
> You will be issued a full refund of your purchase within a week of
>   approval. You will receive the refund in Steam Wallet funds or through
>   the same payment method you used to make the purchase. If, for any
>   reason, Steam is unable to issue a refund via your initial payment
>   method, your Steam Wallet will be credited the full amount. (Some
>   payment methods available through Steam in your country may not
>   support refunding a purchase back to the original payment method.
>   Click here for a full list.)

[source](http://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds?snr=1_41_4__42)

Answer (score 11):

Note that Steam's policy has changed - it is now possible to request a refund. The [Steam Subscriber Agreement](https://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/) now links to the [Steam Refund Policy](https://store.steampowered.com/steam_refunds). Please see other answers which describe this in more detail.

---

It is possible in special circumstances to cancel an order. I managed to undo a preorder of a game that went on sale the day after I preordered it. I contacted customer support, and since I didn't actually *get* the game yet (it wasn't out), they allowed me to cancel my preorder and reorder with the sale price. I don't recall whether my credit card had been charged for the initial order, however.

Answer (score 3):

Steam is described as a "Service" in thier licence agreement etc. They hope this will allow them to avoid most online consumer laws in many countries that categorically state that you are allowed a refund in the case that a game does not work.

If you have a technical problem with a game, you can try to get a refund, but I have never tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Steam may refund an entire order if you file a ticket on their tech support site.  Note, however, they may require you to have a good reason.

The one time I wanted to cancel an order (when I purchased all 3 Borderlands expansions and *then* found out two of them include SecuROM), I opted not to cancel mine, because tech support informed me they would have to refund the entire order, and I had purchased some one day sale items on the same order.